# SQLLDR Database connectivity

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

We are facing database connectivity issues while running `SQL loader utility`.

When I run the job to call sqlldr from my batch file (on windows), I am able to run my job without any issues. But when the same batch file is run from the scheduler, it is failing with below error.

> SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
>   ORA-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable Internal Error.

Can you please suggest the resolution for this.

Please let me know if the details I provided are insufficient.

Comment: Which scheduler? I imagine there are environment variables missing; does explicitly setting everything (ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, PATH, etc.) in your batch file help?

Comment: ORACLE_HOME is set up correctly and while calling SQLLDR i am passing the credentials like below.
    call sqlldr scott/tiger@dbname log=<..> data=<..>
so I don't think ORACLE_SID need to be set up again as dbname is provided in call to sqlldr.